# Passing an array in JQuery with a POST and reading it with Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, flask

I try to store the data from a graph  with jQuery but I always get a 400 Bad request.

The problem is the data_series variable isnt just an array of integers but much more. This is unchangeable since it is necessary for my chart generation to be like this.
A litle piece of it to show you what I mean:

```
data_series[0][data][0][]:1389975624000
data_series[0][data][0][]:91
data_series[0][data][1][]:1390003200000
data_series[0][data][1][]:446
data_series[0][data][2][]:1390089600000
data_series[0][data][2][]:429
.....
```

My Jquery post looks like this,

```
$.ajax({
            url: "{{ url_for('save_graph_to_session') }}",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                data_series: data_series
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Saved to session')
            }
        });
```

On flask side I read it like this, and put in a session:

```
@app.route('/save_graph_to_session', methods=[ 'POST'])
def save_graph_to_session():
    session['data_series'] = request.form['data_series'];
    return "saved"
```

I've tried to post with `'data_series[]:' data_series`, didn't work out either.
EDIT: 
Maybe the solution lies within the way to request, so :
Is there a way to request in flask that ignores the fact that this is an array of arrays

Comment: I think you need to *read* `request.form['data_series[]'];` because jQuery will use PHP naming conventions by default. That's mostly a guess though, I don't know your server side form handling library.

Comment: @Quentin You pointed me in another think-direction. Maybe the problem lies within the way of reading the data. However, your solution doesn't work.. thanks for your time!

Comment: You should probably look at the Net tab of your browser's developers' tools to figure out what data is actually being sent.

Comment: session['data_series'] = request.form.getlist('data_series[]') was the way to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the way one can do this:

```
session['data_series'] = request.form.getlist('data_series[]');
```